# Cucumber and Capybara test failing, how do I debug?

Tags: cucumber, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am brand new to testing w/ Capybara and Cucumber.  I saw some really useful videos on it, and have written my first test.  However, said test is failing and I'm not sure why.

I believe I have all the gems I need and I'm reasonably sure that all the configs are done as per the documentation.

But, when I run the feature, it fails on missing content, but I know the content is in the correct view, and I know that the view is being served correctly.  I can manually navigate, and it looks as it should, but the cucumber/capybara steps are saying it can't find the content.

For my step definition, I have:

```
When I visit the homepage
  get root_path
  response.should have_content("Log In")
end
```

In the application layout, I have the words "Log In" that show when a user is not logged in.

when the feature runs, I get the failure message:

```
expected there to be content "Log In" in ""
```

Is there a way to see what the html is that's being rendered by the response inside the test?  I tried just doing a puts(response) but that didn't do anything.  Any other reason it might be failing that I'm not considering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use save_and_open_page:

http://technicalpickles.com/posts/debugging-cucumber/

Comment: exactly what I was looking for, thanks.  Though, when i see that page, the content I'm looking for is there, so I'm not sure what else I'm missing.

Comment: This link is out of date. File not found.

Comment: @mhatch I don't use Capybara any more, this is from 9 years ago, but if someone shares an updated link I can edit my reply.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the save_and_open_page functions, I find that I like using the launchy gem a bit more.  It seems more cucumber-ish.

If you add to your Gemfile

```
gem 'launchy'
```

And of course run

```
bundle install
```

You can simply in your cucumber test write:

```
When ...
Then show me the page
Then I should see ...
```

The **Then show me the page** will launch the browser as well.  I haven't checked, but I'm guessing it's just sitting on top of the save_and_open_page function, but again, it feels better for me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `visit` not `get`. Moreover it is better to split your step and use standard step `When I go to <page_name>` (See web_steps.rb and paths.rb)

I suggest you to take a look into [rubygems.org](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.org) project - it has cool set of features and you can use it as an example.

Comment: I appreciate the advice on using the standardized names, but after following your advice, I'm still failing the same steps and have the same lack of insight into why.